# Proper way to handle exceptions in SharePoint 2010 project

Tags: sharepoint, exception, sharepoint-2010

I'm new to sharepoint developing, and I need your help to give me advice how to handle potential exceptions in my code. I have this method with `User user` as parameter , in which I'm detecting who is current user , so I can make some query and return information according to his name from `SharePoint List`. What are the possible exceptions that I need to handle , and what is the "good" practice to do that ?

Thank you for your time and your answers.

Here is the code I wrote so far:

```
public void SomeMethod(User user)
{
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Employee object is not created");
    }

    try
    {
        using (SPSite currentSite = new SPSite("SiteName"))
        {
            if (currentSite == null)
            {
                throw new System.UriFormatException("Invalid URL");
            }
            using (SPWeb currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                if (currentWeb.CurrentUser == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("User is not logged in");
                }
                user.Name = currentWeb.CurrentUser.Name;

                if (currentWeb.Lists["ListName"] == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("There is no list with that name");
                }
                SPList myList = currentWeb.Lists["ListName"];
                SPQuery queryRole = new SPQuery();

                queryRole.Query = "SomeQuery";


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (UriFormatException ex)
    {
        throw new UriFormatException(ex.Message);
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you removed some stuff for privacy purposes because im unable to figure out what you're trying to achieve. 
If you need the current user depending on the context this method runs in (Webpart/.aspx/etc.) you could just use SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser

If this is a standalone desktop application you have to make a new web the way you're already doing it but that still does not explain the "user.Name = ..." line.

To at least address the question to some extend its quite pointless to create a exception just to catch it yourself and then throw it again.

```
throw new UriFormatException("...");
...
catch(UriException ex)
{
    throw new UriFormatException(ex.Message);
}
```

The general rule is to only catch exceptions if you want and can handle them. None of your catch blocks actually handle an exception so you might as well remove them all.

To find out potential exceptions the msdn documentation is a good point to start of:

[SPSite(string url)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms466911.aspx)

[SPQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792541/how-do-i-handle-sharepoint-exceptions?rq=1) is a question about sharepoint exception handling